# Any ways to detect Cocos2d-x: CCScrollView is scrolling or not?

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I'm seeking a way to get the scrolling state of `CCScrollView`.

It seems not to be a rare requirement, but do I need to implement it? 
Thanks:)

---

**Edit:** *Following is my two 'brute force' ways, but they seems work.*

The goal is to get the scroll condition of a `CCScrollView` **s** from a `cocos2d::Layer` **l**.

---

**Way #1**

In each iteration of `update()` function of **l**, get the content offset of **s** by

```
ScrollView::getContentOffset()
```

if it stays the same, we can assume that the ScrollView is not scrolling.

---

**Way #2**

Create class **S** which inherits `CCScrollView` and `CCScrollViewDelegate`, then in the override of the delegate's function

```
void scrollViewDidScroll(ScrollView* view)
```

(which seems to be called every time the ScrollView scrolls.) use a variable to save current time

```
/*uint64_t*/ lastScrollTime = mach_absolute_time();
```

then in the `update()` function of **l**, assume the ScrollView is not scrolling by a time threshold

```
curTime = mach_absolute_time();
if (GlobalUtils::machTimeToSecs(curTime - lastScrollTime) > 0.1)
```

Hope that works :)

Comment: Your 'brute force' ways haven't handled the situation where the ScrollView is zooming rather than scrolling. As @alc77 mentioned in his comment, you can use `ScrollView::isDragging()`.

Comment: @GaloisPlusPlus thanks, i didn't know the ScrollView is able to zoom

Comment: Actually i think `isDragging()` is not satisfying because, after user dragged the ScrollView, there is a deaccelerate process before it stops scrolling, but `isDragging()` returns **false** during this period.

Comment: You're right. I haven't noticed this case. But you can still check whether the selector `CC_SCHEDULE_SELECTOR(ScrollView::deaccelerateScrolling)` is scheduled or not.

Answer (score 1):

So, in your's initScroll() method you should set:

```
scrollView = ScrollView::create();
// initialisation scrollview
scrollView->addEventListener(CC_CALLBACK_2(YourScene::testScroll, this));
this->addChild(scrollView);
```

and make `bool` variable `isScrolled`. Then in method `testScroll()` you need to check listener's event type and depending from it set the variable `isScrolled`:

```
void YourScene::testScroll(Ref* sender, ui::ScrollView::EventType type)
{
     if (type == ui::ScrollView::EventType::SCROLLING)
        isScrolling = true;
    else
        isScrolling = false;
}
```

You can see other values `EventType` [here](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/native-cpp/V3.2alpha0/d8/d29/classcocos2d_1_1ui_1_1_scroll_view.html#a2628ea8d12e8b2563c32f05dc7fff6fa)

Comment: Thanks:) but I'm looking for the method for **CCScrowView** instead of **ui::ScrollView** -_-

Comment: Oh, sorry. If we talk about cocos2d-x **v.3.0**, [there is](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/native-cpp/V3.0/d2/d84/classcocos2d_1_1extension_1_1_scroll_view.html#a37f9e37bec4d09e8a2d80afd56fed332) bool variable `isDragging`. But I never used it, I hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks! I've tried but it seems still not works as I expect... I'm now using a 'brute force' method, and it seems working :)

Answer (score 1):

One way without modifying the source code of `CCScrollView` is to check the flag of `ScrollView::isDragging()` and whether one of the scrolling selectors of `ScrollView` is scheduled.

```
bool isDeaccelerateScrolling = scrollView->getScheduler()->isScheduled(CC_SCHEDULE_SELECTOR(ScrollView::deaccelerateScrolling));
bool isPerformedAnimatedScroll = scrollView->getScheduler()->isScheduled(CC_SCHEDULE_SELECTOR(ScrollView::performedAnimatedScroll));
bool isScrolling = scrollView->isDragging() || isDeaccelerateScrolling || isPerformedAnimatedScroll;
```